# SUDO YUM not found

Tags: amazon-ec2, yum, sudo, root

I am running a Amazon ec2 instance on amazon's linux.

Whenever I run anything `sudo yum` it give me this:

```
sudo: yum: command not found

ec2-user$ rpm -qf /usr/bin/yum
yum-3.2.29-30.24.amzn1.noarch

ec2-user$ which yum
/usr/bin/yum
```

`which yum` while in root gives:

```
root$ which yum
/usr/bin/which: no yum in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bn:/usr/local/bin:/opt/aws/bin)
```

This is a new ec2 instance two days old. When I first logged in I ran `sudo yum update` and everything wen't well. What changed?

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo in root's `PATH`.

Instead of `/usr/bin` the path entry reads `/usr/bn`.

I can't be sure if this is because Amazon has screwed up something, or you made a change to your `PATH` and accidentally deleted the `i`, but that appears to be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Where can I change that?

Comment: Wherever you set it initially. Perhaps in `.bashrc`? Though if you didn't set it, it's probably Amazon's fault. I'm not at all impressed with Amazon Linux and I don't recommend it.

Comment: I never set it.

Comment: OK, my recommendation will be "Don't use Amazon Linux". They seem to have a history of breaking important stuff at random times. A real DevOps thing to do, but out here in the real world, we need stable systems.

Comment: Gosh, you may be right. Added `export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH` to `/root/.bashrc` and the error still happened. I had to `sudo su` and run `yum...`.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here: [Passing PATH through sudo](https://superuser.com/a/156695/45920)

```
sudo nano /etc/sudoers
ctrl + w (nano search)
"usr/bn"
replaced it with "usr/bin"
```

Comment: while this may work, you should almost always use `visudo` to edit sudoers (`export EDITOR=nano` first) as it will check the syntax before writing the file; if you mess it up (and it's very easy to do ... been there), you can make it impossible to use sudo, which means your server is hosed.  Also, I think the answer from Michael Hampton above deserves a checkmark, perhaps with a note indicating you also found the sudoers was also messed up.